# How do I fix Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

ALL,

I am using Eclipse SDK 4.2.2 to make an Android application.
During saving of the xml layout files I usually see an error which says:

"Control needs to be followed by />"

In order to fix it all I need to do is select the offending line, hit Ctrl+X, save the result with Ctrl+S, then restore the offending line by Ctrl+V and the error is gone.

Is there a way to fix the Eclipse to not to throw this error?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend moving to Intellij.  That solved several of my eclipse problems.  Permanently.

Comment: Are you building the layout by hand or with the builder, and if by hand, are you copy/pasting data into the window?

Comment: I get similar issues when working with JSP files. Eclipse has bad error support for non-Java sources. I work around it by doing _Select All > Delete > Undo_ as it forces Eclipse to re-parse the file contents for errors. To me, the procedure is better than yours as it doesn't involve the clipboard.

Comment: Update your eclipse. It goes away after an update

Comment: @StevenMann, yes, I'm building by hand in xml editor and no I am not copy/pasting anything. I'm using autocompletion feature there, so everything is correct.

Comment: @SalGad, does this mean that it's a known problem? Also update it to which version?

Comment: Well I'm using Eclipse Indigo 1.4.2 and it works fine for me